# Java, Hibernate java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet cannot be cast to java.util.HashSet

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria, one-to-many

I have two tables, DVD and Contact.

A DVD can be rented to a contact and a contact can rent many DVD's.

The many to one link `(dvd-->contact)` works fine.

But the other way fails: `(contact-->dvd)`

This is the contact mapping:

```
<set name="dvds" inverse="true">
   <key column="contactId"/>
   <one-to-many class="Dvd"/>
</set>
```

Here is setter getter for Contact:

```
private Set<Dvd> dvds = new HashSet<Dvd>();

public Set<Dvd> getDvds(){
   return dvds;
}
public void setDvds(Set<Dvd> dvds){
   this.dvds=dvds;
}
```

When I try to get the DVD rented from a contact with this:

```
HashSet<Dvd> tt = (HashSet<Dvd>)dds;
```

I get an Exception:

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: org.hibernate.collection.PersistentSet 
cannot be cast to java.util.HashSet
```

What does the Exception mean and how do I fix it?

**Edit: This solved my problem:**

```
.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY)
```

Comment: Agree with Bozho's answer, curious to know why you want to convert it to a concrete class, - what was your need to do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You don't need to cast to `HashSet`. It is a `Set`, and it does not provide any additional methods. So just don't cast.

This is a general rule when working with collections - don't refer to them with their concrete classes (unless you really need to). Use `List` and `Set`, rather than `ArrayList` and `HashSet`

Comment: [`HashSet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) does provide extra methods than `Set`, an example is the `clone()` method. I've ran into this problem today and need to manually create my clone now...

Answer (score 9):

Don't try to cast the `Set` `dds` into `HashSet`. Hibernate uses its own implementation of the `Set` interface called `PersistentSet` which does not derive from `HashSet` and hence the casting throws a `ClassCastException`. Either use it through the `Set` interface, or create a new `HashSet` using its constructor (in which case your changes to the set will not be reflected in Hibernate automatically).

```
Set<Dvd> tt = dds;
```

OR

```
HashSet<Dvd> tt = new HashSet<Dvd>(dds);
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer as it addresses the lack of clone() pointed out in another comment.

Answer (score 2):

I've come across this problem recently.
I was able to eradicate the casting problem.

`List<Object> listObject = Arrays.asList(ListFromHibernate.toArray());`

Then you can get the objects by casting the objects in List, say.

`MyObject x = (MyObject) listObject.get(1);`

PS: It's freaking 2013.

Answer (score 1):

[Abhinav Sarkar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4584388/hibernate-and-one-to-many-link/4584436#4584436) is correct of course, but there is also a mistake in your modeling.

The relationship between DVD and Contact is Many-To-Many, not Many-To-One (otherwise each DVD would be unique to one single customer)

Comment: NONO a dvd can only be rent by one and only one user!

Comment: @vinise One user at a given time, yes. But if it can only be rented by one user ever, then you misunderstood the concept of *renting* something.

Comment: yes :) don't worry its a very very specific case
a dvd can be rent by a user and when the user bring it back the field contact (on dvd's row) is set to null ans then can be rent by an other user :)